# Searching for value in registry sub-key

Tags: registry, powershell-2.0, outlook-2010

I'm looking to find the path and data of a specific reg_binary value in a random sub key using Powershell.

If I run the following command it will return all keys and values:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\my outlook profile" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

I only want `reg_binary 00036601` (this determines if the Outlook 2010 profile is cached or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the keys, and get the values out. Although I don't have any called '00036601' on my system.

```
$regRoot = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\outlook profile"
$regKeys = Get-ChildItem $regRoot | where {$_.GetValueNames() -contains '00036601'}

$regKeys | foreach {$_.GetValue('00036601')}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated. It returns a value on my system, maybe you have a different version of Outlook?